# How to debug class library in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, c

I have a solution with two projects

1. My project PortCloud
2. Library Renci.SshNet with source code

I reference from project PortCloud to Renci.SshNet library

When I try to run/debug solution I get exception error in library and application crashes.

Trouble is that I do not see exception in debugger. I would like to see line in library where this is happening and why. What am I doing wrong? Why debugger do not automatically open problematic file and show me exact error?

**Update** Visit http://screencast.com/t/1aIUVX27 video for seeing what I am actually doing in Visual Studio

Comment: What debugger are you using. If you are using VS, do you have it configured to break on all exceptions?

Comment: (1) You're referencing `Renci.SshNet` **at** `PortCloud`, right? (2) Are you running in debug mode? (3) Is the project in debug mode (right click > properties)?

Comment: is the Library project set to Debug also ?

Comment: yes, I run project in Debug mode

Comment: (1) yes, I am referencing Renci.SshNet at PortCloud (2) yes, debug mode (3) yes, project is in debug mode. I am able to debug bugs in PortCloud without problem, just not in the library

Comment: I watched your video, it doesn't look like you have the debugger set to break on all exceptions. Go to debug menu, select exceptions and then set all the check boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Add both the project to your visual studio solution

1. From project, go to reference
2. Add project Reference
3. Add the project which you want to debug.

Run F5 to debug. F10 to step over and F11 to step in to functions

More details for debugging [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn)

Comment: this does not helps. I already have reference but does not solves problem.

Comment: Are you sure you added the ENTIRE PROJECT as reference and not just the library? If you added only the dll as reference then it's not the same thing..

Comment: How can I check this. I am not sure, but I use Project tab

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new unitest project. Then you can add it as a reference to the project and debug it.